# i don't know if these models are setup correctly for django ecommerce

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

`
from django.db import models

from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

## Create your models here.

CATGORIES_CHOICE = (
("Sports"),
("Fashion"),
("Electronics"),
("Fishing"),
("Books"),
("Cosmetics"),
("Games"),
("Pets"),
("Outwear"),
("Lingerie"),
("Medicals")
)

ORDER_HISTORY_CHOICE = ()

class User(models.Model):

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

password = models.CharField(max_length=15)

phone_number = PhoneNumberField(region="US")

address1 = models.TextField()

address2 = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

class Store(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="official store")

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

class Product(models.Model):

```
store_id = models.ForeignKey(Store,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#product_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,max_length=13)

title = models.CharField(max_length=110)

description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)

discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)

available = models.IntegerField()

category = models.CharField(choices="",max_length=20)

# image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")

condition = models.CharField(choices="",max_length=20)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

@property
def sales_price(self):
    return "%f" %(float(self.price * (1 - self.discount)))
```

class CartItem(models.Model):

```
item = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

class Cart(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

order_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=7)

ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem)

created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

class Review(models.Model):

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

product_id = models.ManyToManyField(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1,default=0.0)

label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

comment = models.TextField(max_length=500)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

class BlogPostInfo(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

written_by = models.CharField(max_length=70)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

class Saved(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

class History(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

status = models.CharField(choices="",max_length=20)
`

Comment: Hey, you need to be more specific with what you are asking, this is far too general.

Comment: read this  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. also formate the code blocks correctly

Comment: i don't know the best  model configuration for an ecommerce site

Answer (score 0):

change your category field in Product:

```
category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

and create a Category Class:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) or ""
```

this will allow you to do add any category and it will be on a different table linked by the foreignkey

Comment: don't forget to do your python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate